# Weights are not updated on each iteration in theano

Tags: python, machine-learning, theano

symbolic variables

```
x = T.dmatrix('x')
y = T.dmatrix('y')
```

These are the weights of a neural network

```
W1_vals = np.asarray(rng.randn(input, hidden), dtype=theano.config.floatX)
W1 = shared(value=W1_vals, name='W1')
W2_vals = np.asarray(rng.randn(hidden, output), dtype=theano.config.floatX)
W2 = shared(value=W2_vals, name='W2')


cost = T.mean(T.nnet.categorical_crossentropy(prob_y_given_x, y))
params = [W1, W2]

grads = T.grad(cost, params)
```

update rule is:

```
lr = 0.01
updates = [(param, param-lr*grad) for param, grad in zip(params, grads)]
```

function to train the model

```
train = function(inputs=[x, y], outputs=cost, updates=updates)
```

When I print the values of `W1` and `W2` using `W1.get_value()` and `W2.get_value()` after each iteration of train function is called, I find that only `W2` values are changing whereas `W1` values are same through out and are not changing.

What am I missing in my code?

Comment: apparently everything seems correct, how did you compute `prob_y_given_x` ? The only reason weights don't change is that gradient is zero which can only happen when you are getting correct predictions even from your randomized weights.

Comment: hidden_activations = T.nnet.relu(T.dot(x, W1))
prob_y_given_x = T.nnet.softmax(T.dot(hidden_activations, W2))
It is highly unlikely that correct predictions occur at random weights!

Comment: It turns out gradients wrt `W1` are zero, but why are they becoming zero even with random initialization of weights?